# How create new user with firebase function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a function for firebase, which accepts email for registration, but the function for some reason does not accept the transmitted data and I create an anonymous user.

**my client call function**

```
createInviteUser(email: string) {
    let inviteFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createInviteUser');

inviteFunction({email})
    .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
   console.log(result);
})
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    });
```

}

**server side function**

```
exports.createInviteUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res)=> {
    const email = req.body.email;
        admin.auth().createUser({
            email: email,
            emailVerified: false,
            password: 'secretPassword',
            displayName: 'John Doe',
            photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
            disabled: false
        })
            .then(function (userRecord) {
                // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
                console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
                return res.status(200).send(userRecord);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
            });
});
```

and server side logs

```
12:39:33.697 PM
createInviteUser
Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail
12:42:21.765 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution started
12:42:21.765 PM
createInviteUser
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
12:42:21.792 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution took 27 ms, finished with status code: 204
12:42:22.035 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution started
12:42:22.035 PM
createInviteUser
 Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
12:42:22.400 PM
createInviteUser
Function execution took 366 ms, finished with status code: 401
```

Comment: Looks more like a configuration error looking at those messages. Have a read on the following https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#additional_environment_commands - Or maybe reinitialize firebase. Also since you're using `httpsCallable` change your cloud function from `onRequest` to `functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) =>`

Comment: @Philip yea, if i understand right, in `admin.initalizeApp()` we pass json file with  keys, i have this. What different between onRequest and onCall? How i understand onCall take some metadata as second argument.

Comment: The `The functions.https.onCall trigger automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens.` (So can only be called if your user is authenticated, Otherwise anyone could call your function). You can pass any amount of parameters. eg. inviteFunction({email, id: someId123, text: 'some text'}), and use `data.email`, `data.id` to read it.

Comment: Now i take 401 error. Add json key in `admin.initalizeApp()` be enough? Or need something add more (i not understand moment with `firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"`)?

Comment: Yes `admin.initalizeApp()` is enough, using `functions:config:set someservice.key="someKey"` will enable you to use it in your cloud function like so `functions.config().someservice.key` - However this is not related to the 401 (Unauthorized) issue you're receiving. Are you currently logged into your app when you call `createInviteUser` ? Otherwise you need to revert back to `onRequest` and use a `fetch request` instead of `httpsCallable`

Comment: Yup, in my client have all api configs, and in `admin.initalizeApp()` i pass secret key to. And i think maybe add there express router and don't use for that case function?